# How to force Skype links to open in desktop mode on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, skype

I have a Windows 8 computer recently upgraded to 8.1, and any Skype link I click on the web (in desktop mode) open Skype in metro mode.

Metro mode, for some reason, won't allow me to place any call, while desktop mode works fine.

**How can I force Skype to open `skype:` links in desktop mode?**

Comment: Have you tried to getting rid of the ModernUI Skype application considering it does not allow you to make a call its not exactly a big loss.

Comment: @Ramhound I'd be happy to do that, but I've followed some instructions to uninstall Skype and reinstall what was thought to be the desktop application only, but unfortunately it reinstalled both versions...

Comment: The Skype Desktop application does not install the Skype found on on the `Windows Store `.  You are also able to simply uninstall the ModernUI Skype I have do so myself on my own Windows 8.1 system.

Comment: Oh, I might just have uninstalled the desktop version then! How do you specifically uninstall the metro version?

Comment: Just like any other ModernUI application you right click it to access the shortcut properties.  One of the options is to remove the application.  The desktop version as of the last release does not install both versions ( it can't be changed to do this ) because the same .exe is used for all versions of Windows.  Skype is not yet a built feature, and even if it was, it could be disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Finally got it to work with your method, thank you! I also realized that the metro version was not using the same account as the desktop version (one of them was using a `live:` prefix in front of the email address), and this is why the fullscreen version didn't work: it simply had no credit. Please add your method as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

To change that go to:
Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Default Programs -> Set Default Programs

Select Skype for desktop -> Choose defaults for this program
I that window you can select the links the desktop version uses.